# How to return to calling page after form posting in zf2

Tags: forms, routes, zend-framework2

I would like to have an `editAction` return to the page that called it after the form has been posted.  I know that I can configure the router to pass the url of the calling page to the controller so that the controller can return to that page after the form has been submitted.  However, I am interested in whether zf2 has a simpler method.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly then you can add this after the form has validated:

`return $this->redirect()->toRoute(null, array(), array(), true));`

this will redirect the request to the same page, reusing all the route params (that's what that `true` param value is for). So will end up on the same page, but with clean `$_POST` superarray. You can also look into using the `flashmessenger` controller plugin to pass messages between requests, to inform user whether the form passed validation etc.